# IOS - Basic Authentication with a REST API - SSL - AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-3

Everything works great with the code, the problem is it says authentication failed, though the username and password is 100% correct, so not sure if there is a way to pass the login and the password and get the user authenticated

```
 NSString *urlString = @"URL";

        NSMutableArray * keyStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSMutableArray * valueStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
        [keyStrings addObject:@"user"];
        [valueStrings addObject:@"abc"];
        [keyStrings addObject:@"password"];
        [valueStrings addObject:@"12345"];

        NSDictionary * requestDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:valueStrings forKeys:keyStrings];
        AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/xml"];
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
        manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
        manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're intending to use [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) in which case you should be using the `Authorization` header field instead of passing the username and password in plain text within the request's parameters (I made this mistake the first time I tried to do Basic Authentication with a REST API).

You will need to add it to the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`'s headers which you can do by utilizing the [`setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:password:` method](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:password:) or by constructing the header field value manually and setting the header field value using the [`setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` method](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:).